# Create and Filling arc progressively with css - circle progress bar

Tags: html, css, animation, progress-bar

I'm struggling to fill an arc like a progress bar because I'm not that good working with css.

I want to achieve a "progress" arc like this:
[image]

I came across with this: https://codepen.io/enslavedeagle/pen/AXzaKE

```
#arc,
#arc::before {
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 100%;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: transparent;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#arc {
  border: solid #00BBEE 12px;
  clip: rect(0px, 100px, 50px, 0px);
  margin: 25px;
}

#arc::before {
  content: '';
  border: solid black 12px;
  top: -12px;
  left: -12px;
  clip: rect(0px, 100px, 50px, 0px);
  transform: rotate(-150deg);
  /* define the fill length, using the rotation above.
     from -180deg (0% fill) to 0deg (100% fill) */
  /* if you have a better solution to make thing like this 
     work, please let me know! :) */
}
```

and try to customize to be like what I want to but with no sucess until now: here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qpNrEP

Could any one give some help with this? Can also be alternative solution to achieve this.

I appreciate

Kind regards,

Comment: can you use jquery or just css?

Comment: I can use angular 4

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use an SVG with two arc on on top of the other and then use `stroke-dash-array`.

```css
svg {
  height: 90vh;
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
}

path {
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke-width: 2;
}

path.grey {
  stroke: lightgrey;
}

path.purple {
  stroke: purple;
  stroke-dasharray: calc(40 * 3.142 * 1.85);
  stroke-dashoffset: 20;
  /* adjust last number for variance */
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewbox="0 0 100 100">
    <path class="grey" d="M40,90
             A40,40 0 1,1 60,90"
          style="fill:none;"/>
    <path class="purple" d="M40,90
             A40,40 0 1,1 60,90"
          style="fill:none;"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: That's what I was looking for...now I just need to map the value of  `stroke-dashoffset` to 0-100% to make the progress works. I would like to upvote one thousand times! Thank you so much! Do you mind to explain how the calc of `stroke-dasharray` (calc(40 * 3.142 * 1.85)) works?

Comment: It's a little more complicated that it sounds as you probably need JS to determine the actual dash array and dash offset. The calc is *roughly* (radius * Pi * any range). It does break though if you're rough with it. As i said these are usually managed by JS. This is just to demo the concept.

Comment: I'll use angular to manage, no problem. I just want to know how to draw the arc and fill it (`stroke-dasharray`). I asked because I'm not used to work with geometric forms...so I don't get how do you came to this result, like: why 1.85? on the calc form? If its possible could we talk on chat? Thanks again

Comment: Hi, can you tell me how to make the progress bar bigger ?

Comment: Although I also wonder about the `1.85` (while `40 * 3.142` being the radius times pi), I found `calc(40 * 3.142 * 1.85 * (1 - <fraction>))` to fill a fraction defined by a handy `<fraction>` given in the range from 0 to 1.

Comment: Ah, the 1.85 is needed to get the length of the whole arc. The full circle would be `radius * pi * 2`. But since the bottom piece is missing, the factor is only 1.85. The details depend on how `M40,90 A40,40 0 1,1 60,90` results in a circular arc.

Answer (score 3):

Using SVG is the best way to create an arc like this.
Here is the solution with all iterations of the loader:

```css
.progress-wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

path {
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke-width: 6;
}

.grey {
  stroke: #e5e5e5;
}

.red {
  stroke: #e33800;
  stroke-dasharray: 248;
  stroke-dashoffset: 240;
  /* adjust last number for variance */
}

.red-02 {
  stroke-dashoffset: 220;
}

.red-03 {
  stroke-dashoffset: 200;
}

.red-04 {
  stroke-dashoffset: 180;
}

.red-05 {
  stroke-dashoffset: 160;
}

.red-06 {
  stroke-dashoffset: 140;
}

.red-07 {
  stroke-dashoffset: 120;
}

.red-08 {
  stroke-dashoffset: 100;
}

.red-09 {
  stroke-dashoffset: 50;
}

.red-10 {
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="progress-wrapper">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="37 -5 120 100" width="120" height="100">
      <path class="grey" d="M55,90
               A55,55 0 1,1 140,90"
            style="fill:none;"/>
      <path class="red" d="M55,90
               A55,55 0 1,1 140,90"
            style="fill:none;"/>
  </svg>
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="37 -5 120 100" width="120" height="100">
      <path class="grey" d="M55,90
               A55,55 0 1,1 140,90"
            style="fill:none;"/>
      <path class="red red-02" d="M55,90
               A55,55 0 1,1 140,90"
            style="fill:none;"/>
  </svg>
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="37 -5 120 100" width="120" height="100">
      <path class="grey" d="M55,90
               A55,55 0 1,1 140,90"
            style="fill:none;"/>
      <path class="red red-03" d="M55,90
               A55,55 0 1,1 140,90"
            style="fill:none;"/>
  </svg>
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="37 -5 120 100" width="120" height="100">
      <path class="grey" d="M55,90
               A55,55 0 1,1 140,90"
            style="fill:none;"/>
      <path class="red red-04" d="M55,90
               A55,55 0 1,1 140,90"
            style="fill:none;"/>
  </svg>
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="37 -5 120 100" width="120" height="100">
      <path class="grey" d="M55,90
               A55,55 0 1,1 140,90"
            style="fill:none;"/>
      <path class="red red-05" d="M55,90
               A55,55 0 1,1 140,90"
            style="fill:none;"/>
  </svg>
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="37 -5 120 100" width="120" height="100">
      <path class="grey" d="M55,90
               A55,55 0 1,1 140,90"
            style="fill:none;"/>
      <path class="red red-06" d="M55,90
               A55,55 0 1,1 140,90"
            style="fill:none;"/>
  </svg>
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="37 -5 120 100" width="120" height="100">
      <path class="grey" d="M55,90
               A55,55 0 1,1 140,90"
            style="fill:none;"/>
      <path class="red red-07" d="M55,90
               A55,55 0 1,1 140,90"
            style="fill:none;"/>
  </svg>
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="37 -5 120 100" width="120" height="100">
      <path class="grey" d="M55,90
               A55,55 0 1,1 140,90"
            style="fill:none;"/>
      <path class="red red-08" d="M55,90
               A55,55 0 1,1 140,90"
            style="fill:none;"/>
  </svg>
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="37 -5 120 100" width="120" height="100">
      <path class="grey" d="M55,90
               A55,55 0 1,1 140,90"
            style="fill:none;"/>
      <path class="red red-09" d="M55,90
               A55,55 0 1,1 140,90"
            style="fill:none;"/>
  </svg>
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="37 -5 120 100" width="120" height="100">
      <path class="grey" d="M55,90
               A55,55 0 1,1 140,90"
            style="fill:none;"/>
      <path class="red red-10" d="M55,90
               A55,55 0 1,1 140,90"
            style="fill:none;"/>
  </svg>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/shalinigandhi/pen/mdmmwdV

Answer (score 1):

After not finding the answer I liked here I did some work myself and made a [Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LoMJaj) that you can use that makes progress bars exactly as you described with the inputs being: the amount of degrees of a circle that should be 100%, the radius of the circle and the percentage you to have filled.
[Progress bar example (image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fH131.png)

HTML:

```
<section class="stat" id="sectionId">
  <svg viewbox="0 0 100 100">
    <path class="bar" d="
    M 10, 50
    a 40,40 0 1,0 80,0
    a 40,40 0 1,0 -80,0
   "/>
    <path class="progress" d="
      M 10, 50
    a 40,40 0 1,0 80,0
    a 40,40 0 1,0 -80,0
    "/>
  </svg>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    _.makeProgressBar("01", 240, 40, 86);
  </script>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
.stat {
  width: 200px;
}

svg {
  display: block;
  transform-origin: center center;
  transform: rotate( 90deg );
}

path {
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke-width: 6px ;
  fill:none;
}
```

JS:

```
_ = {};

//this is a self executing function, it keeps the global namespace clean
(function(win, doc, helper){

  helper.makeProgressBar = function(id, totalDegrees, radius, percentage) {
    var section = doc.getElementById(id);
    var svg = section.children[0];
    var bar = svg.children[0];
    var progress = svg.children[1];

    if(percentage > 100){
        percentage = 100;
    }
    if(percentage < 0){
        percentage = 0;
    }

    var percentageDegrees = calculateDegreesFromPercentage(totalDegrees, percentage);

    var barDash = calculateDash(totalDegrees, radius);
    var barGap = calculateDash ( 360 - totalDegrees, radius) * 2;

    var progressDash = calculateDash(percentageDegrees, radius);
    var progressGap = calculateDash(360 - percentageDegrees, radius) * 2;

    var rotation = 0 - ((totalDegrees - percentageDegrees) / 2);

    bar.setAttribute("style", "stroke: #707070; fill: none; stroke-dasharray: " + barDash + " " + barGap + ";");
    progress.setAttribute("style", "stroke: #23CE39; fill: none; stroke-dasharray: " + progressDash + " " + progressGap + "; transform-origin: center center; transform: rotate("+ rotation +"deg)");
  }

  calculateDegreesFromPercentage = function(totalDegrees, percentage) {
    return totalDegrees/100*percentage;
  }

  calculateDash = function(degrees, radius) {
    return degrees * Math.PI / 180 * 0.5 * radius;
  }
})(window, document, _);
```

Comment: The screenshot looks great but the Codepen doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @Christophe Sorry for the slow reply, I just checked it and for some reason the site had to think for a good few seconds before working but it did still work without me making any changes. Did you press the button to make the progress bar appear?

Answer (score 0):

I've just created a plnker in Angular 2 which I think it's exactly what you want.

It manage the fill of the second arc with a variable:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewbox="0 0 100 100">
    <path class="grey" d="M40,90 A40,40 0 1,1 60,90" style="fill:none;"/>
    <path [ngStyle]="{'stroke-dashoffset':percentPath}" class="blue" d="M40,90 A40,40 0 1,1 60,90" style="fill:none;"/>
</svg>
```

Then, in the component I call a function which take the value from a slider with min=0 and max=100:

```
this.percentPath=(233-(V*2.33)); //233 is the maximun number stroke-dashoffset needs to disapear the second path
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/KNPThi?p=info

take it a look!

Comment: thanks but from the answer I've created a component that can be use dynamically. You can check on: https://elmeerr.github.io/ng2-arc-progress-demo/

Comment: Cool!! It's amazing. I was going to do the component but you already done that. Thanks!

Comment: @ElmerDantas Have you ever tried to animate the arc from 0 to the corresponding value when the page has finished loading? Now I have that issue

Comment: I don't know if I get it but, it's not the case to use  a `for` from 0 to corresponding value and then increment  the variable you use as model to fill the arc progress?