# How do I animate SVG stroke to act as a gauge?

Tags: html, css, svg, css-animations, stroke

I have this code set up:

```css
.gauge {
  stroke-dasharray: 1000;
  stroke-dashoffset: 500;
  animation: dash 5s linear alternate;
}

@keyframes dash {
  from {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/style.css">
  <title>Gauge</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="gauge">
    <svg width="500" height="500" fill="white" stroke="red" stroke-width="25" stroke-linecap="round">
      <circle cx="200" cy="200" r="100"/>
    </svg>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

What I'd like to do is to turn it into a gauge as this (forget about the color & All):

[image]

I'm having hard trouble understanding the dasharray & dashoffset commands in order to transform it into what I need...can anyone help with that?

Comment: the length of the path (circle) is 623.32. Use this value for the stroke-dasharray and for the stroke-dashoffset. Also if your gauge has 100 units in order to know the length of 1 unit you need to divide 623.32 by 100 i.e 2*Math.PI.   Also please read this article: https://css-tricks.com/svg-line-animation-works/

Comment: Even easier, set `pathLength` to 100 and no calculations are needed.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47910146/create-and-filling-arc-progressively-with-css-circle-progress-bar/47910783#47910783

Comment: https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/yLgzpXm

Answer (score 0):

Animating either `stroke-dashoffset` or `stroke-dasharray` depends partly on the use case. Here I find it easier to 1) rotate the circle with transform/rotate and 2) animate the `stroke-dasharray`.

A prerequisite is setting the pathLength attribute. Setting it on a `<circle>` will control the the length of a full circle. In this case it looks more or less like the gauge is 2/3 of a circle. So, it makes sense for the full circle to be 150 and 2/3 is then 100.

Now the length of the gauge can be controlled by the first value in the `stroke-dasharray`. The second value should just grater than 100 -- it is the length of the space between the line in the array.

```css
.gauge {
  stroke-dasharray: 100 150;
  animation: dash 5s linear alternate;
}

@keyframes dash {
  from {
    stroke-dasharray: 100 150;
  }
  to {
    stroke-dasharray: 0 150;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/style.css">
  <title>Gauge</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="gauge">
    <svg width="500" height="500" fill="white" stroke="red" stroke-width="25" stroke-linecap="round">
      <circle transform="rotate(150 200 200)" cx="200" cy="200" r="100" pathLength="150"/>
    </svg>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```